# Adjusting the height of \vline

Tags: rules

Is there a way to adjust the height of `\vline`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the height and depth of a `\vrule` is not specified, then they are taken from the surrounding box. But it is possible to specify them explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\mbox{%
  \vline
  A
  \vline height 1ex
}

\mbox{%
  \vline
  B
  \vline height 5pt depth 3pt width 1pt
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: hmm I wonder if the lack of a `\relax` in `vline` allowing it to parse a following `height` was intentional, it's very un-latex-like: +1 anyway:-)

Answer (score 4):

`\vline` is designed to make a rule exactly as heigh as the surrounding box so it has no^* control over the height. The LaTeX `\rule` command has explicit arguments to give the height and width of the rule, so you may be looking for that.

See @Heiko's answer for a partial contradiction to this statement.

Comment: the depth of tex's `\vrule`s was plumbed a long time ago.  see the [tugboat warning](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-2/tb21beet-warn.pdf), on the second page toward the end.