# How can I make a vertical rule that extends to the edges of an fbox?

Tags: boxes, rules, fbox

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\fbox{some text \vrule{} more text}
\fbox{some text \vrule{} more deep text}
\fbox{some text \vrule{} more $\int$ tall text}
\end{document}
```

In all three cases, the `\vrule` stretches to the height of the surrounding box, but doesn't touch the edges of the `\fbox` because of the `\fboxsep`.

**How can I make the `\vrule` stretch by an extra `\fboxsep` on each side?**  I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84830/adjusting-the-height-of-vline), but it only covers giving an explicit height to the `\vrule`, while I'd like to extend it by a given amount, but otherwise let it expand and shrink as appropriate to fill the current box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\smash{\vrule}`, but you have to specify the height and depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{\fbox{some text more text}}%
\fbox{some text \smash{\vrule height\ht0 depth\dp0} more text}
\sbox0{\fbox{some text more deep text}}%
\fbox{some text \smash{\vrule height\ht0 depth\dp0} more deep text}
\sbox0{\fbox{some text more $\int$ tall text}}%
\fbox{some text \smash{\vrule height\ht0 depth\dp0} more $\int$ tall text}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Or you could just use `\strut`s and make all your `\fbox`es the same height.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\strut some text}\hspace{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\strut some text}
\fbox{\strut some text}\hspace{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\strut more deep text}
\fbox{\strut some text}\hspace{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\strut more $\int$ tall text}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: This is a great idea. Thanks! For the record, I ended up doing this with a twist: instead of repeating the argument to fbox, I ended up making two new commands: one to draw the vrule, and one to draw the box.  The box-drawing one starts by measuring its argument with the vrule-alias set to `{}`, then prints its argument again, this time with the vrule-alias redefined to make a rule of the appropriate height.

Answer (score 4):

one way is to set `\fboxsep` to zero and than instead `\vrule` use accordingly set `\rule`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\newcommand\VR{\rule[-0.4\baselineskip]{0.4pt}{1.2\baselineskip} }

\begin{document}
\fbox{ some text \VR qjf more text }
\fbox{ some text \VR more deep text }
\fbox{ some text \VR more $\int$ tall text }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this only works if you know the size of your box in advance (and all are the same). Ideally, I'd like to preserve the natural heights of the boxes.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a `tabular` to me.

```
\documentclass{article} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/121799
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
\hline
some text & more text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
\hline
some text & more deep text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
\hline
some text & more $\displaystyle\int$ tall text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can adjust the padding.

```
\documentclass{article} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/121799
% commands based on
\newcommand{\Tstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand{\Bstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand{\TBstrut}[2]{\Tstrut{#1}\Bstrut{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{20}{c|}}
\hline
some text & more text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|*{20}{c|}}
\hline
\TBstrut{2.5ex}{1.5ex}some text & more deep text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|*{20}{c|}}
\hline
\TBstrut{4ex}{3ex}some text & more $\displaystyle\int$ tall text & and more \\[0.5ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make it a command and as long as you have less than 20 rules e.g.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand{\PartitionedBox}[2][20]{\begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{l|}} \hline #2\\ \hline \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
 \PartitionedBox{123 & abc & xyz}
\end{document}
```

works. (Thanks to JouleV for suggesting to use the option.)

[image]

Comment: Hah! Very smart. Annoyingly, though, that requires counting the 'columns' at every use.

Comment: @Clément Yes, that's a valid point which can be easily addressed.

Comment: Excellent point! I didn't think of it, but of course adding too many columns is a neat trick :) So many good answers :'( ^^

Answer (score 4):

You can measure the text's natural height and depth, add the current `\fboxsep` and retypeset with a suitable strut and kerns on either side, by setting also `\fboxsep` to zero.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\vfbox}{m}
 {
  \clement_vfbox:n { #1 }
 }

\box_new:N \l__clement_vfbox_box
\dim_new:N \l__clement_vfbox_ht_dim
\dim_new:N \l__clement_vfbox_dp_dim
\dim_new:N \l__clement_vfbox_sep_dim

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \dim_set:Nn \l__clement_vfbox_sep_dim { \fboxsep }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \clement_vfbox_strut:nn
 {
  \vrule height #1 depth #2 width 0pt
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \clement_vfbox:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep { \l__clement_vfbox_sep_dim }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__clement_vfbox_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__clement_vfbox_ht_dim { \box_ht:N \l__clement_vfbox_box + \fboxsep }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__clement_vfbox_dp_dim { \box_dp:N \l__clement_vfbox_box + \fboxsep }
  \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep { 0pt }
  \fbox
   {
    \clement_vfbox_strut:nn { \l__clement_vfbox_ht_dim } { \l__clement_vfbox_dp_dim }
    \kern \l__clement_vfbox_sep_dim
    #1
    \kern \l__clement_vfbox_sep_dim
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\vfbox{some text \vrule{} more text}
\vfbox{some text \vrule{} more deep text}

\bigskip

\vfbox{some text \vrule{} more $\int$ tall text}
\vfbox{some text \vrule{} more $\displaystyle\int$ tall text}

\bigskip

\vfbox{some text \vrule{} \vfbox{some text \vrule{} other} other}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I still have a bit of trouble with ExplSyntax, but I *think* I understand what this does.  Am I correct to think that this solution defines a macro that measures its argument and stores its height and depth in two newly defined lengths, and then typesets the argument with fboxsep set to 0 (thereby allowing the vrule to span the whole box), adding struts and kerns to replicate the original box padding?